# Return Value After Filter method is not filtering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Been Trying to filter out the thumbnail values that equal to 'self' or default, but its still not working , is there any other way other than filter ?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#result').empty();
    var userInput = $('input').val()
        $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url:"https://www.reddit.com/r/" + userInput + ".json?jsonp",
        success:success
    })
    })

function success(response){
    var result ="";
    $.each(response, function(index, value){
        var list = response.data.children
        $.each(list.filter(function(item){
            return item.data.thumbnail !== "self" || "default"
        }), 
            function(index,value){
                var thumbnail = value.data.thumbnail
                var author = value.data.author
                result += "<li>" + 
                            "<img src='" + thumbnail + "' class='reddit-image'/>"

                result += "<p class='reddit-author'>" + author + "</p>"
                result += "</li>"
                $('#result').html(result)
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: What is issue with `javascript` at Question? Are `item.data.thumbnail` having value of  `"default"` being returned? `return item.data.thumbnail !== "self" ||  item.data.thumbnail !==  "default"`

Comment: Yes, values of "self" & "default" are still being returned

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement says if the value isn't `'self'` return the **string** `'default'`

The string `'default'` is truthy

You need to compare the variable to both strings

```
 return item.data.thumbnail !== "self" || item.data.thumbnail !== "default"
```

Comment: I think my function is causing it,  I don't think its receiving the filtered data , could you take a look at it please?